# Restoring MO from ao2mo using PYSCF module

Tags: pyscf

After finishing the orthonormalization of IAOs basis, and the LO.boys localization I am building my hamiltonian:

```
na,nb = mol.nelectron//2,mol.nelectron//2
E0 = mol.energy_nuc()
h1 = np.einsum('ab,ai,bk->ik',mf.get_hcore(),C,C)
h2 = ao2mo.restore(4,ao2mo.kernel(mol,C),n)
```

I am seem to not being able to make the transformation from my new orbital coefficients (`C`,[344,14]) and I can later transform to a (105,105) matrix containing my coefficients with a size of 11025 coeff.

When I try to run the `ao2mo.restore(symm,eri,nao_orb,tao)` with `eri = ao2mo.kernel(mol,C)` I get this error:

> ```
> 185         return eri.reshape(npair,norb,norb)
> 187 else:
> 188     raise RuntimeError('eri.size = %d, norb = %d' % (eri.size, norb))
> RuntimeError: eri.size = 11025, norb = 8
> ```

I am directly introducing this transformation, but I am stuck at this transformation. I have tried several symmetries stated in the documentation, but I am running out of ideas.
The source code, can be found in [this_repository](https://github.com/StefanoBarison/quantum_simulation_with_IAO)

I thank you for your time and help.